# Can I configure IIS to use an ASPX page for all OPTIONS request

Tags: iis, iis8, aspx

Is there a way I can configure IIS 8 to use an options.aspx page for all requests coming in with the method OPTIONS?

Also can a vbscripted aspx page set a response header?